# converting object to byte array in silverlight

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-5.0

```
    private byte[] ObjectToByteArray(Object obj)
    {
        if (obj == null)
            return null;
        BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        bf.Serialize(ms, obj);
        return ms.ToArray();
    }


    private Object ByteArrayToObject(byte[] arrBytes)
    {
        MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream();
        BinaryFormatter binForm = new BinaryFormatter();
        memStream.Write(arrBytes, 0, arrBytes.Length);
        memStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        Object obj = (Object)binForm.Deserialize(memStream);
        return obj;
    }
```

i can't do that process in silverligth, didn't define "BinaryFormatter" class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such class as BinaryFormatter nor SoapFormatter for Silverlight, but you can use the [DataContractJsonSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.json.datacontractjsonserializer%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) that is supported in Silverlight.

Comment: Do you have a different method does not accept all the objects?